# Laravel 5: 'Invalid argument supplied for foreach' after creating Service Provider

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've already sort of found an alternative way to do this, but i would really like to know why after creating a service provider i get this error:

**ErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 120:
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

These are the steps i followed to create a service provider:

1-php artisan make:provider UserServiceProvider

2-adding `'App\Providers\UserServiceProvider::class'` to the providers Array in `config/app.php`

am i missing something?

the alternative way i used to resolve this was registering all my services in `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

Comment: You'll have to provide actual code, including the source code for ProviderRepository, to get a helpful answer from the community.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that I didn't return an array in the service provider's `provides` method:

```
public function provides()
{
    return [];
}
```